# Display error from asp.net GridView.RowUpdating

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an `<asp:GridView>` component where row editing has been enabled through `<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />`. I then hook up the C# code that handles the update through `GridView.RowUpdating += GridView_RowUpdating;`.  Then, from within `GridView_RowUpdating`, I can detect different errors (ex: duplicate object). When an error condition occurs, I would like to:

1. cancel the edition : this can be done by doing `e.Cancel = true` where `e` is a `GridViewUpdateEventArgs`
2. display an error message.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to display the error message. Any hint on how to do that?

Comment: Using the Caption property of the Gridview is simplest, style it with CSS.  Otherwise can use something like a hidden <asp:Label> or <asp:Literal> that you reveal if an error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. I've added some examples to the `RowUpdating` method.

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //if there is an error
    if (errorFound == true)
    {
        //cancel the edit by setting editindex to -1 and rebind the grid
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();

        //display the error in a label placed outside the grid
        Label1.Text = "There was an error";
        Label1.Visible = true;

        //or display javascript error message
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showError", "alert('There was an error');", true);

        //or do not set the editindex back to -1, but show an error in the edititem template itself
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Label label = row.FindControl("Label2") as Label;
        label.Text = "There was an error in the textbox";
        label.Visible = true;
    }
}
```